# calculating differences between timestamps and storing in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, timestamp, python-3.6

I have a dictionary called times containing a datetime timestamp as the key and tuple as the value. Example formatting is as follows:

```
{datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 4, 20, 2): ('A', 'B'),
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 4, 19, 59): ('C', 'D'), 
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 4, 19, 55): ('E', 'F'), …, }
```

I am trying to sort the timestamps in a list in ascending order, loop through the list to calculate the difference between consecutive timestamps, and then store the starting time in a new dictionary if the delta is greater than a 10 minute threshold (with the corresponding tuple as the value).

This is what I have for code so far. I believe I need to first store the difference between timestamps in the list time_with_breaks then use an if statement store deltas that are greater than the threshold in the dictionary but I'm not sure how to do this.

```
deltas = {} # store timestamp and seconds until next entry
time_with_breaks = [] # store timing information of breaks
# sorted list of time stamps (ascending order)
timelist = sorted(playlist_dict.keys(), reverse=False)
for i in timelist:
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What does this mean? `and then store the starting time in a new dictionary if the delta is greater than a 10 minute threshold` - the time is the key but what is the value of this dict?

Comment: @IainShelvington just updated the question. the value would be the tuple corresponding to the starting time that meets the 10 minute time difference threshold

Comment: Are you opposed to using a DataFrame for this?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I would ideally like to avoid them

Comment: @thomascheng3636 what will you be doing with the result of this? You want to loop over only entries that are separated by more than 10 minutes?

Comment: @IainShelvington yes, I simply want to find the starting time and associated tuple of entries that are

Comment: That have a starting time more than 10 minutes after the previous entry?

Comment: @IainShelvington my apologies, times that the next start time doesnt occur until 10 min later

Comment: @thomascheng3636 Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
# This will return an ordered list of the timestamps
times_sorted = list(sorted(playlist_dict.keys()))
time_with_breaks = []
# "zipping" the list with itself offset by 1 will give you an iterable
# of each timestamp and the next timestamp in the list
for time_1, time_2 in zip(times_sorted, times_sorted[1:]):
    # datetime - datetime results in a timedelta
    # 600 seconds is 10 minutes
    if (time_2 - time_1).seconds > 600:
        # Append the datetime where the next datetime in the list is more than
        # 10 minutes away
        time_with_breaks.append(time_1)
```